# AS3 - hitTestObject with dynamic MovieClips added through For Loops

Tags: actionscript-3

I've been attempting to set up a hitTestObject function in a project I've been working on recently and have encountered some difficulty.

This is because I'm trying to do it with MovieClip instances dynamically added through a For Loop. The MovieClips being added are called 'square' and when I left Mouse Click I add a series of these MovieClips to the stage. My problem is that I want to listen out for a hitTestObject of 'square' intercepting 'square' and subsequent additions of the same MovieClip.

I've set up a numerical variable that increments up by 1 each time I add the group of 'square' MovieClips through left click to the stage and I've assigned this number along with a string to combine together to create a square.name instance.

In my case the first group of MovieClips added would have a .name instance called 'Square 1' and then 'Square 2' on the second mouse click and so on.

I've also added and pushed each name through into a container array for referencing later.

So how can I actually reference these dynamic names in a hitTestObject argument using my .name instance and array??

I'm sure it is obvious and I've done the groundwork so any help to point this out to me would be greatly appriciated.

Many Thanks.

Comment: If you could please show your ground-work, I realize you've explained (fairly well) here but having to think up what your code looks like adds difficulty to answering it.

Comment: I can completely understand your point @shaunhusain and I will post my code within the next few hours in order to add more foundation to my question, but in the mean time I suppose the crux of my query relates to the key hitTestObject line of code -   if (square.hitTestObject(square)) {
    trace("Contact Made");
   }                                       Now obviously this wouldn't work for the question I've asked but in order to reference my 'square' MovieClip and differentiate between them would I use get childByName, or reference 'square' as square[i] and tie this to .name in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible way assuming you are trying to do this in the timeline and you have a MovieClip subclass in the library called 'Square'. Beware of modifying the array while the hitTests are being performed. If you want to remove squares, wait till after all tests have completed, or make a copy of the squares array.

```
var squares: Array = [];

function addSquares(n: int): void {
    var square: MovieClip;

    for (var i: int = 0;
    i < n;
    i++) {
        square = new Square();
        square.name = "square" + i;
        addChild(square);
        squares.push(square);
    }
}


function checkHits(): void {
    var square: MovieClip;
    var checkSquare: MovieClip;

    for (var i: int = 0;
    i < squares.length;
    i++) {
        square = squares[i];

        for (var j: int = i + 1;
        j < squares.length;
        j++) {
            checkSquare = squares[j];

            if (square.hitTestObject(checkSquare)) {
                squaresHit(square, checkSquare);
            }
        }
    }
}


function squaresHit(square1, square2): void {
    // do something
    trace("squaresHit:" + square1.name + "," + square2.name);
}


addSquares(4);
checkHits();

//squaresHit:square0,square1
//squaresHit:square0,square2
//squaresHit:square0,square3
//squaresHit:square1,square2
//squaresHit:square1,square3
//squaresHit:square2,square3
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this @dezza and taking the time to construct this section of code on my behalf - from reading this through it certainly looks along the lines of what I was attempting to produce. The addSquares function essentially covers my existing setup really well, although I'm producing this code within a Class rather than on the timeline, but it's the code in the checkHits function that looks key to solving my issue with the construction of the secondary loop staggered at +1 and hitTesting between the 2 var MovieClips - will try this out and let you know how it goes. Many Thanks again

Comment: Thanks @dazza - I've managed to get this code implemented into my project now and hit detection is now occurring between two MovieClips with the same initial instance name. If anybody else has this problem then the 'checkHits()' function in the code dazza supplied will be a good place to look and build on from!